# Prove or disprove the convergence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Prove or disprove that $$\int_0^\infty \left|\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right|dx < \infty.$$

I tried by Wolframalpha and this integral seems to satisfy the Cauchy property, but I do not know how to prove it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Estimate $$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\lvert \sin x\rvert}{x}\,dx.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you explain more specific, please? How could we estimate that integral?

Comment: Find a lower bound so that the series of lower bounds diverges [or an upper bound so that the series of upper bounds converges, but in this case, we have divergence].

Comment: as well as an estimate, you could try and show that the integral below is a lower bound, then show that it is possible to always collect a finite number of these in order to add the same value each time to the total integral - if you are familar with the summation $\Sigma^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ 

 - then consider this integral as lower bound $\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \frac{\lvert \sin x\rvert}{(k+1)\pi}\,dx$

Comment: BTW is it ok to say $X < \infty$